# Evaluate $\sum_x\big(\frac{x}{p}\big), \sum_x\big(\frac{x+k}{p}\big), \sum_x\big(\frac{ax+b}{p}\big)$ where $p$ is prime and the rests are integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Evaluate the following sums:

$$\sum^{p}_{x=1}\left(\frac{x}{p}\right), \sum^{p}_{x=1}\left(\frac{x+k}{p}\right), \sum^{p}_{x=1}\left(\frac{ax+b}{p}\right)$$

Let $p$ be a prime and $k, a,$ and $b$ be arbitrary integers.

If someone could explain this to me and perhaps share a resource where I could learn how to solve these types of questions better, I would be indebted.

Comment: Why the rewrite?

Comment: I didn't realize I could fit in the actual question into the subject line. Your comments were helpful. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. :)

Comment: No problem. I think you can get the the last one. If it is as simple as it looks on it's face it may be helpful to review the laws of summations. 

$\sum A+B =\sum A+ \sum B$ etc

Answer (score 4):

Observe the first sum is equals to sum of p-first natural numbers times the inverse of p, use the formule of sum arithimetic progression, the others are analogous.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum^{p}_{x=1}(\frac{x}{p})=\frac{1}{p}\sum^{p}_{x=1}x=\frac{1}{p}\frac{p(p-1)}{2}=\frac{p-1}{2}$$

$$\sum^{p}_{x=1}(\frac{x+k}{p})=\frac{1}{p}\sum^{p}_{x=1}x+k=\frac{1}{p}\big (\frac{p(p-1)}{2}+pk \big)=\frac{p-1}{2}+k $$

The last summation follows in the exact same way... you split it up.

$$\sum^{p}_{x=1}(\frac{ax+b}{p})$$

Comment: So it would be $\frac{a(p-1)}{2}+b$ for the last one?

Comment: Looks good to me!